# Production example of Jetpack Compose App?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Is there open source production example of Jetpack Compose App? I want to check how to work with complex **state** in Compose?

I am rewriting one whole app to Compose and stuck on how to represent complex states for screen and components.

For example let we have some Filter screen for Movie app where we can select/deselect genres, ratings, counties, years and so on.

How to represent the state of entire Filter screen?

```
enum class FilterType {
    Genre,
    Rating,
    Country,
    Year,
}

class FilterItemState1(
    val name: String,
    val type: FilterType,
    selected: Boolean
) {
    var selected by mutableStateOf(selected)
}

data class FilterItemState2(
    val name: String,
    val type: FilterType,
    val selected: Boolean,
)
```

```
Option 1:

data class FilterScreenState(
    val listOfFilters: List<FilterItemState1>
)

If you now want to change selection item you change observable selected variable:

item.selected = !item.selected
```

```
Option 2:

data class FilterScreenState(
    val listOfFilters: SnapshotStateList<FilterItemState>
)

If you now want to change selection item you change element inside observable listOfFilters:

state.listOfFilters.set(index, item.copy(selected = !item.selected))
```

Which option is better and when I should use one or another? It's good to have some production Compose app as reference code.

Answer (score 0):

You have:

- https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi in production
  and also you can check for official sample
- https://github.com/android/nowinandroid

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommended to you check the following links carefully:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer/stateholders
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Take seriously the danger of perfectionism in coding and take everything for granted. Even the example codes of Compose developed by the best Android developers have inconsistencies.

```kotlin
enum class FilterType {
    Genre,
    Rating,
    Country,
    Year,
}

data class FilterItem(
    val name: String,
    val type: FilterType,
    val selected: Boolean,
)

data class FilterUiState(
    val filterItems: List<FilterItem>
)

@Composable
fun FilterScreen() {
    var uiState by remember { 
        mutableStateOf(FilterUiState(filterItems = listOf(..))) 
    }
    
    SideEffect {
        val updatedItems = uiState.filterItems.mapIndexed { index, item ->
            if (index == 0) item.copy(selected = true)
        }
        uiState = uiState.copy(filterItems = updatedItems)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have readed already that links. How ones can help me with my concrete example of state for select/deselect item ?

Comment: yes, I also used your approach with immutable collection and copying whole collection with only one item changed. But it's not efficient - to change only one item you need to copy WHOLE collection! Imagine you have 10k items?

So, there should be another more efficient approach - may be mutableStateListOf, or listOf<mutableStateOf> as my example with mutableStateof selected item

Comment: @aleksandr Don't worry about these issues, even if your list has 100k items, you won't have any problems, and of course, it is better for large lists despatch to background thread and return result to main thread.

Comment: @aleksandr All bases have asked this question at the beginning and you are not the first person to worry about this

Comment: hmmm. Agree, for small lists copying is OK. For large you suggest dispatch to back thread. But if you really dispatch to back thread you need to wait finish of operation. So, while you waiting you will need to show progress bar for user and all this just for changing one element?!  Sound for me as bad arch.

What do you think about solutions with 
a) mutableStateListOf
b) listOf(mutableStateOf)

a) and b) I found in Jetsurvey, and other Google examples. 
And yes, I agree, that Google samples are not consistent for me